# React Native autoCorrect suggestions are not visible

Tags: react-native, expo, textinput, autocorrect

I am in need of some help.

I am unable to have the text input keyboard display the autocorrect suggestions. The function works when entered into expo snack, but not on any devices I am using with the expo app, both android and iOS. I have tried applying autoCorrect={true} with the same results. Code and screenshots below. Is this an expo configuration issue somehow? This has me really stuck. Thanks for any help.

edit: expo snack link https://snack.expo.io/S1!cDJ0RS

[image: Not Working through expo app]

[image: Working on expo snack]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default function RespondScreen() {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');

  return (
   <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', flex:1}}>

    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  </View>  
  );
}
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: can you share an expo snack so that we can check?

Comment: Sure, added to original message. https://snack.expo.io/S1!cDJ0RS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe an issue with your phones keyboard you are checking coz , ive tried it in my phones expo, and its working fine. See the screenshot below ,

[image]

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: do check once, and its actually the solution , do upvote and mark as accepted so that it can help others :)

Comment: great :) glad it helped